# Colpitts oscillator not functioning

Tags: voltage, oscillator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP3SKf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't understand how the circuit works .I know it is a Colpitts oscillator but the part where I get confused is that in the video on youtube it says we can set Ve = 1/2VCC however I don't understand how this can happen since we don't have a base resistor and the emitter resistor will try to draw as much  current as the emitter current but this isn't possible because the voltage drop on the emitter resistor cant be more than VCC . I am not sure if this circuit can work based on that I wrote earlier.Can somebody explain it to me please?

Comment: R2/R3 form a voltage divider. Let's assume the base is at 1/2VCC - what is the voltage at the emitter? Note - as the voltage on the emitter rises, the base current drops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If R2 is the same value as R3 then they will project a DC voltage onto the base of about 50% of Vcc. The emitter will be about 0.7 volts below that. The emitter current will then be approximately half Vcc minus 0.7 volts divided by Re.

> *I know it is a Colpitts oscillator but the part where I get confused
> is that in the video on youtube it says we can set Ve = 1/2VCC*

By making R2 a little smaller than R3, the base voltage can be adjusted to be half Vcc plus 0.7 volts thus, the emitter voltage will be half Vcc.